# Delphi7 TQuickRep просмотр в своем окне ошибка Access violation

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

В моем приложении определено несколько отчетов TQuickRep. Все отчеты просматриваются через компонент TQRPreview в отдельной форме. В принципе все работает:

Обработчики событий на QuickRepPreview

```
procedure TqrQuikViewer.QuickRepPreview(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fmPreprint.QRPreview1.QRPrinter:=TQRPrinter(Sender);
  fmPreprint.QRPreview1.QRPrinter:=(sender as TQuickRep).QRPrinter;
  fmPreprint.Show;
end;
```

Репорты вызываются на просмотр процедурой

```
procedure Tfm._preview(qr: TQuickRep);
    procedure _view;
      begin
                qr.Prepare;
                fmPreprint.sb.Panels[3].Text := inttostr(qr.QRPrinter.PageCount);
                fmPreprint.sb.Panels[1].Text := inttostr(fmPreprint.QRPreview1.PageNumber);
                qr.QRPrinter.Free;
                qr.QRPrinter:=nil;
                qr.preview;
      end;

 procedure _say(const e:Exception);
      begin
                        tablo('Ошибка просмотра !');
                        ShowMessage('Класс ошибки :'+e.ClassName+chr(13)+
                       'Ошибка :'+e.Message);

      end;

  begin
  try
    _view;
  except
      on E: Exception do
           _say(e);
  end; //try

  end;
```

После нескольких успешных вызовов просмотра вылазит Access Violation причем это может быть любая строчка из

```
   qr.Prepare;
   fmPreprint.sb.Panels[3].Text:=inttostr(qr.QRPrinter.PageCount);
   fmPreprint.sb.Panels[1].Text:=inttostr(fmPreprint.QRPreview1.PageNumber);
   qr.QRPrinter.Free;
```

Куда здесь стоит копать  ?

Comment: строчка fmPreprint.QRPreview1.QRPrinter:=(sender as TQuickRep).QRPrinter; закомментирована , почему-то не скопировалось ..

Comment: Зачем вы делаете `qr.QRPrinter.Free;` ?

Comment: Освобождаю память .. собственно , комментил эту строчку  - результата не дало ..

Comment: Объект создается - TQRPrinter(Sender) , память бы и освободить

Comment: А вообще- иду канве http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=489

Comment: `TQRPrinter(Sender)` - это не создание объекта.